# My Tabs are not aligned with each other and instead just align itself on the left

Tags: html, css, navigation, tabs

Im trying to make a tabs where if they click it, a new line of text would appear below. My problem is that the tab buttons does not look good. They are not aligned to each other. Please help me align the tabs (im very sorry for my poor english).

Here are my files:

https://github.com/okii43434/-/tree/main

I tried using grid as display and change the grid column and grid row but it does not work

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre]. The latter belongs directly into your question, do not just send us to some external platform to see your current code.

Comment: Start with making your labels `.mytabs label { flex: 1 }` and take it from there...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I removed the `flex` to put `grid`, then I added the parameter
`grid-template-columns: repeat(3, minmax(0, 1fr));` which creates lines
of 3 repeating columns, then for content I added `grid-column: span 3 / span 3;` which tells the div to take 3 slots.

```css
    body {
        background: #016412;
    }
    .mytabs {
        font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        max-width: 600px;
        margin: 70px auto;
        padding: 25px;
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(3, minmax(0, 1fr));
    }
    .mytabs input[type="radio"] {
        display: none;
    }
    .mytabs label {
        padding: 25px;
        background: #e2e2e2;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    .mytabs .tab {
        padding: 20px;
        width: auto;
        background: #fff;
        order: 1;
        display: none;
        grid-column: span 3 / span 3;
    }
    .mytabs .tab h2 {
        font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;;
        font-size: 3em;
    }

    .mytabs input[type='radio']:checked + label + .tab {
        display: block;
    }

    .mytabs input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
        background: #fff;
    }
```